# Using systemd and rc-local server, chmod returns no such file or directory

Tags: linux, bash, systemd

I'm having an issue with permissions set to system files resetting after a reboot.  I am setting up systemd and rc-local services to run a bash script on startup which set the permissions back to how I want them.

I have successfully set up systemd and rc-local services which run a script in `/etc/rc.local`.

My script in `rc.local` reads:

```
#! /bin/bash
cd /dev/
sudo chmod a+rw vmnet0
sudo chmod a+rw vmnet1
```

After rebooting, I notice that `/dev/vmnet0` and `/dev/vmnet1` still have incorrect permissions.  When I run `systemctl status rc-local` I notice that `chmod` is complaining it does not see the `/dev/vmnet0` and `/dev/vmnet1` files.  Exact information returned is:

```
pam_unix(sudo:session) session opened for user root by (did=0)
chmod: cannot access 'vmnet0': no such file or directory
pam_unix(sudo:session) session closed for user root
root : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/dev ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/chmod a+rw vmnet1
pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
chmod: cannot access 'vmnet1': No such file or directory
pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
rc-local.service:c Control process existed, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
rc-local.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Failed to start /etc/rc.local Compatibility.
```

I'm pulling my hair out figuring out why the script, running as root, can't see the `/dev/vmnet0` and `/dev/vmnet1` files.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.) You don’t need to use sudo in a systemd unit such as rc-local.service, all commands already run as root.  In fact, unless you have a really good reason, never use sudo in a systemd service.

2.) Most likely rc-local.service is running before (or at least simultaneously with) the service that loads the driver that creates those device files.  It’s an ordering problem. You’d be better off creating a new systemd service unit, and have it start `After=vmware-networks.service` (assuming that’s the name of the VMware service that loads the driver)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up to not use sudo in rc-local.service.  I also think you may be right about it being an ordering issue.  I solved it by placing the commands in an existing script that loads the applications' services.  The application I was dealing with was VMWare, and the exact solution is posted here: https://gist.github.com/mhtsai1010/e6f3442cefc34ae7069dc2b5e690577c